# Get pixel color in java

Tags: java, performance

I know this is an expensive operation and I already tried to use the `robot.getPixelColor()` function but it works slow, can only calculate like 5 times in a second.

What I'm saying is that 5 times is too small for what I actually want to do, but 20 should be enough. So I ask you if you can suggest me some optimisations to make to my actual code in order to get this result.

My code is:

```
while (true) {
    color = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);
    red = color.getRed();
    green = color.getGreen();
    blue = color.getBlue();
    // do a few other operations in constant time
}
```

I don't know if this would help, but `x` and `y` don't change inside the `while` loop. So it's all the time the same pixel coordinates.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The pixel color will be taken from a game which will run at the same time with the java program, it will keep changing. The only thing is that are always the same coordinates.

Comment: Maybe try creating a temporary thread or two extra? Then stop them when operation is done?

Comment: I'm not very sure what you mean. My point is that I want it to reconsider the pixel color at least once in 0.05s.

Comment: In your while loop have more than one thread run the getPixelColor method. If you're not familiar with multi-threading then go to here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ I would write out the solution for you but kinda awkward from my tablet :).

Comment: What do you mean the pixels will be taken from a game? Is the game the same program that your code is in? or is it another game outside of your program?

Comment: It's a different program. I'm running them both at the same time and my program should take that pixel color and do some things (the constant time operations mentioned above).

Comment: Seems like the multithreading method worked just fine. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the color is represented as a 32-bit int encoded as ARGB. In that case, instead of calling a method, you could just do bit masking to extract the colors, and that may end up being faster because you don't waste the overhead of calling a method. I'd recommend doing something like this:

```
int color = robot.getPixelColor(x,y);
int redBitMask = 0x00FF0000;
int greenBitMask = 0x0000FF00;
int blueBitMask = 0x000000FF;
int extractedRed = (color & redBitMask) >> 16;
int extractedGreen = (color & greenBitMask) >> 8;
int extractedBlue = (color & blueBitMask);
```

Bit shifting and bitwise operations tend to be very fast.

Comment: No, `color` isn't represented as an integer.

Comment: How is `color` represented then? If you want to optimize your code for speed and performance, you're probably going to want to limit your method calls, and object creation and just deal with primitives.

Comment: I know what you say, but the `getPixelColor` function is the one who eats the most time (I tested it). The other 3 functions are just "harmless". The `color` variable's type is `Color` from `java.awt.Color`

Comment: What are you getting the pixel color from? If it's an image or something, you could just try reading the appropriate bytes from the image directly and then casting the bytes to an int. Keep in mind that if you're reading the images from disk or something, file I/O is going to be expensive and slow

Comment: Edited the question, please check.